# Hallmarks of a Professional PHP Programmer

Tags: php, professionalism

I'm a 19 year old student who really REALLY enjoys programming, and I'm hoping to glean from your years of experience here. At present, I'm studying PHP every chance I get, and have been for about 3 years, although I've never taken any formal classes. I'd love to some day be a programmer full time, and make a good career of it.

My question to you is this: What do you consider to be the hallmarks or traits of a professional programmer? Mainly in the field of PHP, but other, more generalized qualifications are also more than welcome, as I think PHP is more of  a hobbyist language and may not be the language of choice in the eyes of potential employers. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Above all, I don't want to waste time on something that isn't worth while.

I'm currently feeling pretty confident in my knowledge of PHP as a language, and I know that I could build just about anything I need and have it "work", but I feel sorely lacking in design concepts and code structure. I can even write object oriented code, but in my personal opinion, that isn't worth a hill of beans if it isn't organized well. For this reason, I bought Matt Zandstra's book "PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice" and have been reading that a little every day.

Anyway, I'm starting to digress a little here, so back to the original question. What advice would you give to an aspiring programmer who wants to make an impact in this field?

Also, on a side note, I've been working on a project with a friend of mine that would give a fairly good idea of where I'm at coding wise. I'm gonna give a link, I don't want anyone to feel as though I'm pushing or spamming here, so don't click it if you don't want to. But if you are interested on giving some feedback there as well, you can see the code on github. I'm known as The Craw there.

https://github.com/PureChat/PureChat--Beta-/tree/

Comment: "I'm known as The Craw there." - perhaps we should be talking about the clawmarks of a professional PHP developer ... :-)

Comment: Claw marks.. I like that! It sounds more aggressive... or something. Heh.

Comment: I'd say that the earmarks of a professional PHP developer are no different to a developer using any other language

Comment: I'll +1 if only because I like that the word "earmark" in this question seems to have confused a lot of people. :)

Comment: For one thing, knowing [when `stripslashes()` is required](https://github.com/PureChat/PureChat--Beta-/blob/master/index.php) ;)

Comment: @phant0m, how would you suggest removing magic quotes? I've been after this issue for quite a while, and haven't found a decent solution. Since we're going for a distributed software, there's no guarantee users will be able to turn it off in their ini file, and ini_set() doesn't have any effect on magic quotes at all. For that reason, this is the "best" albeit crumby solution we could come up with.

Answer (score 13):

**1. High-quality code**

It's easy to write code, but much harder to write good, clean code. And by good, I mean readable code which matches a specific style, is commented enough but not too much, has short methods, self-documenting names of variables, etc.

**2. Broad knowledge**

One can hardly be called a professional developer if he only knows one programming language. Understanding different paradigms (like object oriented, functional or reflective) is a must-have too.

Also, as a web developer, one should know HTTP, JavaScript, SQL, REST and too many things to be listed here. A professional web developer should be able to do an average-scale website alone, with the exception of visual design and graphics. It shouldn't be as good as a website created by a team of highly specialized people, but still should be acceptable.

Knowing your tools is a requirement too. You should be familiar enough with version control, IDEs, etc.

**3. Solid experience**

You don't get professional after two years of college. Somebody with ten years professional experience will likely have more chances of being called a professional developer.

Of course, there are different sorts of experience. Working in a small company where nobody cares about product quality is not very valuable.

An experience in a large-scale project is nice too. It's pretty easy to build a small website, but much harder to get it right when it comes to a website which should be deployed on an array of servers, rely heavily on caching, etc.

**4. Personal motivation**

If a person is truly motivated by software development, she should be able to show it. When I interview a person who claims to be passionate about programming and has 15 years experience in software development, but can't answer the simple question: "Talk me about your last personal project related to programming", I know that there is something wrong with this candidate.

Have open source projects with source code available for download. Have a blog. Participate to Stack Exchange. All those things are valuable when presenting yourself as a professional developer.

Comment: +1. I'd add team work. Developing in a small team/shop is nothing like developing in a large team/shop, even when you are in of a small team within that large team/shop.

Comment: This is great stuff, thanks! I'll be bookmarking this page and referring to it regularly. I'll also be looking into REST, as you suggested. :)

Comment: Good answer. But to me, good code includes to be correct :)

Answer (score 9):

I've been developing with PHP for 8 years now - since I was 16.  I meet people of all ages, shapes and sizes and backgrounds.  I agree with most of MainMa's points, but let me add some emphasize and  a few points of my own.

**Passion & Motivation**

This is the most important thing by far.  Strive to be the best (you can be), and eventually you will.  It takes true passion for problem solving and honing your craft.  You can tell in 5 seconds if somebody is passionate.  When you ask them a question, do they instantly engage, or do they give a two-word response?  If you recommend something, do they come back and tell you about it after?

**Dedication**

Software development is a craft that can take decades to master. They say it takes 10,000 hours to master something, but I think when working with a moving target like software development, it's much more.  If you work full time, you will hit that mark every few years so you can constantly re-invent yourself.  Being able to stick with something this long requires an enormous amount patience & again, passion.  Be wary of the people with 10/15 years of experience who are not incredible.  They are not dedicated, and probably lost the passion a decade ago.  15 years of experience is not the same as 1 year of experience 15 times.

**Hunger for Knowledge**

It takes constant learning and defeat.  It should be downright embarassing/depressing looking at code from the previous year  If it's not, then you aren't learning enough. Find the people who are at the top and learn everything you can from them.  Typically that's key open source contributors (for PHP: Symfony, Zend, PHPUnit/Behat/etc. developers). They are the ones who train everyone else. When somebody tells you X is better than Y, do your own research.  They are usually sheep who were told that 5 years ago and still preach it.  I've actually this site to be an amazing resource.  I find a very wide range of content which usually leads back to the same key people or principals (Martin Fowler, Uncle Bob, etc., DDD, etc.)

**PHP Sucks**

Whatever.  If people want to rag on you/PHP, don't let it get you down.  If you follow the key development principles and actually *build software*, then keep on keeping on.  PHP has come a long way and it's not the ugly duckling it used to be. Learn from other languages, and mess around with others once and a while.  You may like them more, or you may not.  Either way, it'll widen your knowledge and introduce you to new patterns or practices that aren't popular or even possible in PHP.

**Network**

Start building a brand for yourself.  Blog.  Attend meetups/conferences. Reach out to others on Twitter.  Find a community/niche to engage with.  Contribute to open-source projects.  Programming is a very social job now.  Don't isolate yourself, and make your work known.  The sooner you do this, the sooner you'll build relationships with great developers who will take you under their wing, and the sooner you'll find decent clients/employers rather than the crappy ones that everyone else works for.

Comment: I like your comment about code from the previous year. I am constantly reminded how little I actually know in the grand scheme of things every year, but I have that hunger to make my hate for old code less each year :)

Comment: Gotta say, this post really helped put things in perspective for me. Especially the parts about putting myself out there and getting into a good, established project or two. That makes a lot of sense. And I will definitely try to find a group of people who have been doing this for a long time and know the answers to the tough questions. At the places I hang out now, if I ask a question about the composite pattern for instance, people give me that space alien look. xD

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [Adrian Schneider](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175358/6384) and [MainMa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175356/6384) has written (which are both good), I do think that one hallmark of a professional programmer, regardless of language, is **the realization that code has an extremely long half-life** -- much longer than we commonly realize or for that matter expect when writing it.

Yes, there are extreme cases of systems dating back 50 years still in active use (business-critical applications written in COBOL back in the 1960s to 1970s still being used), but it doesn't need to be quite that extreme. Of course at the other extreme is ad-hoc code written to be executed only once. One of the applications I work on is basically a web-based CRUD application. Lots of table views, some specialized views, some reports, a few surrounding odds and ends. Really, nothing very fancy in the grand scheme of things. With *some of the core classes and database code dating back 10+ years* currently, I do believe it rather nicely fits around the median. The language and framework (C#.NET, in this particular case) have of course evolved over that time, and the people involved have gained experience in using it, but the old code remains in place because it works and works well enough, seeing minor changes now and then but most often just providing the foundation that the whole system rests on. My employment before that was centered around replacing an aging system which was designed for only a single user and with parts written 15+ years prior with something slightly more modern. Let me rephrase that. *Some of the most important parts of the system I was tasked with replacing predated Windows 3.0.*

*A professional programmer will, when writing code that isn't **explicitly** throwaway code* designed to solve a very specific one-time-only issue, consider the fact that the code s/he writes today will likely remain in some form for many years. If it is a core piece of the software, it is likely to remain for a significant portion of the product's lifetime. It is likely to need maintenance down the road by a programmer which has nothing to do with the original development team. Heck, it might even need maintenance by the programmer who originally wrote it! (If you don't get that, consider the saying that *code you wrote six months ago may as well have been written by someone else* -- then try six years rather than six months.)

From this comes the realization that **code needs to be easy to read and understand**, **easy to modify** and **easy to extend** to fit into new uses or meet changing requirements. It also needs to be **easy to debug**, as well as preferably **easy to follow** *without* running it through an interactive debugger.

Comment: +1.  If you freelance or build products on your own this is especially true.  You are **personally** held responsible.  While not as extreme as 50 years, I still have old clients/customers coming back to me from 5-8 years ago wanting updates done to products I've built.  My position now?  If you are good, you will want to be replaceable.  People who aren't are typically abusing their clients with long maintenance contracts. (business is business, I guess)